# pd.rename(): cannot rename pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rename columns of a pandas data frame by
using the rename() method. but its not working. below is my code.

The expected result is data frame with columns Features and Scores, but i am getting the column names as Features. Please let me know what is wrong here

```
best_features = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2,k=5)
fit = best_features.fit(X,y)

dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)
feature_scores = pd.concat([dfcolumns, dfscores], axis = 1)

mapper = {0:'Features', 1:'Scores'}
feature_scores.rename(mapper = mapper, axis = 'columns', inplace = True)
feature_scores
```

```
    Features    Features
0   CRIM    5332.588364
1   ZN  6060.725499
2   INDUS   826.590604
3   CHAS    61.917087
4   NOX 5.073299
5   RM  21.981504
6   AGE 2201.715129
7   DIS 163.919426
8   RAD 1445.257647
9   TAX 14817.836927
10  PTRATIO 45.692587
11  B   3340.486412
12  LSTAT   1329.940743
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two columns seem to have an initial name of `0`, so you can't map.

Use:

```
feature_scores = pd.DataFrame({'Features': fit.scores_, 'Scores': X.columns})
```

Or:

```
pd.concat({'Features': dfcolumns[0], 'Scores': dfscores[0]}, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Assuming we just want to overwrite the columns `set_axis` could be used. `feature_scores = feature_scores.set_axis(['Features', 'Scores'], axis='columns')`

Comment: @Henry yes, but this seems to be a lot of unnecessary steps when they could get the initial DataFrame from the constructor ;)

Comment: I agree the first option is definitely the best approach.